# Is it possible to wait for some cards to leave the stack to use them for delve?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Imagine the situation:

---

- I am at 2 life;
- I have five Forests untapped in the battlefield;
- I have 4 [Giant Growth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGiant%20Growth%5d) and 1 [Become Immense](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBecome%20Immense%5d) in my hand;
- I have a [Brainstorm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrainstorm%5d) in my graveyard;
- I have a 1/1 creature with no abilities

---

- My opponent has 19 life;
- My opponent has a 2/2 creature with no abilities.

---

I attack with my creature without casting any cards.
My opponent doesn't block.
Can I cast the 4 Giant Growths (+12/+12) using four of my five Forests and then cast the Become Immense (giving me a total of +18/+18) delving the four Giant Growth and the Brainstorm using the last Forest?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can. After each spell resolves but before the next one on the stack, both players get priority. You can cast more instants or activate more abilities then. Become Immense is an instant, and you are able to pay the mana costs, so you can put it on the stack.

A simpler way to look at this particular example is, you can cast Giant Growth (resolves), then Giant Growth (resolves), then Giant Growth (resolves), then Giant Growth (resolves), and with the stack empty, cast Become Immense.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Short answer.

Long answer:

After blockers are declared, active player (you) gains priority, at this point you can either pass priority or play a spell or activate abilities that work at instant speed.

- You cast Giant Growth, pay the cost and place the spell on the stack.
- You then pass priority for your opponent to respond, they have no answers and pass priority back.
- The spell resolves
- Active player gains priority

It is important to know you gain priority every time you decide to go from one phase to another as well.

So yes after you have cast each giant growth individually, you can then cast become immense for the win

> 116.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the big paragraph about the mechanics of the modern dredge deck probably isn't helping, as it's mostly not relevant, or at least not clear how it's relevant.

Comment: idea was to explain the priority between phases...

Comment: @murgatroid99 I've edited it now...I would hazzard a guess on who downvoted it (he/she does so with my comments every time)

Comment: @fireshark519 it all balances out in the end. Also If you do have a serial down-voter the system will eventually recognize them and void their votes on your posts. [(meta)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

If your opponent has already declined to block, you are in the declare blockers step.  The step following this is the combat damage step, so in order for these spells to change the amount of combat damage you deal, you need cast them in the declare blockers step.  The relevant rule is that declare blockers step only ends when all players (including you) decide you have nothing left you want to do:

> 500.2 A phase or step in which players receive priority ends when the stack is empty and all players pass in succession.  Simply having the stack become empty doesn’t cause such a phase or step to end; all players have to pass in succession with the stack empty. Because of this, each player gets a chance to add new things to the stack before that phase or step ends.

Thus, you can let the 4 Giant Growths finish resolving (letting them go to the graveyard) and then use them to pay the delve cost on Become Immense all within the declare blockers step.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

In fact, you've probably done it a million times before:

1. Cast a creature spell.
2. Wait for it to resolve.
3. Cast another creature spell.

There are four ways a card can be removed from the stack:

- When it's countered or otherwise removed by the effect of some other spell or ability.
- When it's about to resolve, but all of its targets have become illegal.
- As part of resolving,

  - By its own effect. (e.g. [Teferi's Protection](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%27s%5d%2b%5bProtection%5d))
  - As the last step of resolving.

After each of those, players always gain priority (though the other player may gain priority first).

> 116.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.